# ASP.NET Core 6 How to redirect from one view to other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

tl:dr:
I would love to redirect from my Layout view into an index view of a certain class. I do not want to do it through a button.

After I log in the layout page changes depending on your role. If you have a regular user role I want you to be immediately redirected to another view.
This the part of the code where I would like the redirecting to take place. In the "else" clause.
[image]

Is there a simple way about please?
I was thinkig of calling a method from a controller of said class which would simply have the redirect method inside. But that has failed since I was not able to call such method simply in a view and I failed to find a way after a long google search.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to redirect the view from layout to another view, I suggest you could consider using the    `Context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogIn");`

More details ,you could refer to below example:

```
@if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    

}else
{
    Context.Response.Redirect("/home/Privacy");

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the only issue now is the "too many redirects error". Any idea what to do about that?

Comment: Since you put these codes isnide the layout view, your another view also use this layout to solve this issue, you should add another check to check current request path is this view path or not. Like this `@if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Context.Request.Path == "/home/index")`

Comment: Thank you! For my layout I had to use this if @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Context.Request.Path == "/") with nothing but / in my path. But lo, it works! Have a wonderful day!